# How to render apart blocks of a cone

Tags: opengl

in OpenGL I want to render a cone in parts like on the image. My problem is to calculate the arc of each block in 3D space.
   [image]

has someone an idea how to handle this?

Comment: Are you asking how to manually build a 3d model?

Comment: What's an "arc of a block"?

Answer (score 1):

You should not do that manually. Get a 3D modelling app (there are plenty free apps available) and make the model there, then import it in your program and use it there.

If you need to hide parts of the model (alike the 90 degree section on you picture) then mark the blocks with e.g. different surfaces (tags) and choose to render or to skip them from render in your app depending on your conditions.

Comment: Thank you for this idea. But what is, if I had a dynamic size of blocks on each axis?

Comment: @501-notimplemented: You should outline possible cases and do an analysis. Maybe you can get away with modelling 3 cones, or maybe you indeed need the procedural generation on-the-fly. Once you do that, update your question.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the arc of each block, do this:

```
float arcDegrees = 360 / number_of_blocks_in_a_cylinder;
```

In your image, for example, each "ring" of blocks is constructed of 12 blocks (the nearest three blocks aren't drawn in the image, but for the purposes of spacing, we pretend they're there)

This means that each block covers an arc of 360 / 12 == 30 degrees (π/6 radians).  It doesn't matter how close or far from the center they are -- each block in the image covers an arc of exactly 30 degrees.

And that is how you calculate the arc of each block.